# Deadlock during garbage collection in mixed C#/C++-CLI application

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c++-cli, deadlock, windbg

While testing a C#/C++-CLI application I am running into an application deadlock which appears to trace back to the garbage collector.

The application is running on Windows 10 LTSC 2019, Target framework for the majority of libraries is 4.7.2 .  The deadlock appears intermittently, generally after at least 8 hours of continuous run time via automated testing.

It appears to consistently deadlock with the same culprit threads/characteristics.  Specifically:

1. The main/UI thread is idle.
2. A background thread is in the middle of allocating buffer space for incoming image data, which triggers a GC (thread 57 in coming example).
3. A second background thread is processing incoming data from a different source (thread 9 in coming example).

To diagnose, I've run the system until the deadlock is reproduced, then taken and analyzed process dump files.

Using windbg !threads, the following three threads seem to be of interest

```
   9    9  4e4 000002093a48abd0    2b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000002091eec3210 0     MTA 
  57   54  f3c 000002098a6c7760    27220 Cooperative 0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000002091eec3210 1     STA (GC) 
  71   74 1b50 0000020983f20770     1600 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000002091eec3210 0     Ukn
```

Starting with thread 57, it has the following (trimmed) stacktrace:

```
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
04 0000004c`9a5fe280 00007ff8`2330a607 : 00000000`00000000 0000004c`9a5fe3c0 00000000`00000001 00000209`83f20770 : clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x7c
05 0000004c`9a5fe310 00007ff8`2330a580 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : clr!WKS::gc_heap::create_bgc_thread+0x6f
06 0000004c`9a5fe340 00007ff8`233bc70e : 00000000`00000001 0000004c`9a5fe3c0 00000000`00000000 00007ff8`23b2bee8 : clr!WKS::gc_heap::prepare_bgc_thread+0x33
07 0000004c`9a5fe370 00007ff8`232a6019 : 00000209`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!WKS::gc_heap::garbage_collect+0x383
08 0000004c`9a5fe3f0 00007ff8`23309cdd : 00000000`000001ea 00000209`00000002 00000000`00000002 00007ff8`231e503d : clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollectGeneration+0x10d
09 0000004c`9a5fe450 00007ff8`2325f596 : 00007ff8`23309c50 0000004c`9a5fe530 00000000`00000002 00007ff8`231e521c : clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollect+0x8d
0a 0000004c`9a5fe4a0 00007ff8`2325f50d : 00007ff8`23246e70 00007ff8`23b24c28 00000209`8a6c7760 ffffffff`fffffffe : clr!GCInterface::GarbageCollectModeAny+0x4e
0b 0000004c`9a5fe4f0 00007ff8`2328d314 : 00000209`00000002 00007ff8`23b2fa80 00000000`00700000 00007ff8`231e4ed5 : clr!GCInterface::AddMemoryPressure+0x9e
0c 0000004c`9a5fe570 00007ff8`2067828f : 00000000`00000800 0000004c`9a5fe5f0 0000004c`9a5fe620 00007ff7`c40405e6 : clr!GCInterface::_AddMemoryPressure+0x35
0d 0000004c`9a5fe5c0 00007ff7`44dd5e54 : 00007ff7`c52cc6e8 00000000`00000800 00000209`24f3f050 00007ff7`c403fb3f : mscorlib_ni!System.GC.AddMemoryPressure(Int64)$##6000E97+0x6f
!clrstack
0000004c9a5fe5f0 00007ff83b0df6f4 [InlinedCallFrame: 0000004c9a5fe5f0] System.GC._AddMemoryPressure(UInt64)
0000004c9a5fe5f0 00007ff82067828f [InlinedCallFrame: 0000004c9a5fe5f0] System.GC._AddMemoryPressure(UInt64)
0000004c9a5fe5c0 00007ff82067828f System.GC.AddMemoryPressure(Int64)
0000004c9a5fe720 00007ff744dd5d2c MyFirstManagedCProject.Image..ctor(MyFirstManagedCProject.Imaging.ImageFrame)
0000004c9a5fea30 00007ff7c4dce65a MyCSharpProject.RunImageThread()
```

This thread is responsible for collecting/allocating buffers for incoming images.  As part of this, a c++-CLI ctor for an image object adds memory pressure.  In instances where the application deadlocks, this results in a garbage collection occurring.

However the garbage collection is never able to get further than attempting to create the background garbage collection thread.  A naive reading of the arguments suggests that it is attempting to create thread 00000209`83f20770 (thread 71 from above), however it is never signaled.

Looking then at thread 71 we have the following:

```
Kv
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
03 0000004c`9cdfef60 00007ff8`3b049bbc : 00000000`00000000 0000004c`fffffffa 0000004c`8b438000 00007ff8`381fc1d0 : ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0xd9
04 0000004c`9cdfefd0 00007ff8`3b049ad0 : 0000004c`9cdff080 0000004c`9cdff090 00007ff8`381fc130 0000004c`9cdff0b0 : ntdll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended+0xdc
05 0000004c`9cdff000 00007ff8`3811856e : 0000004c`9cdff0b0 00007ff8`381fc130 00000000`00000000 00000000`000002d8 : ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x40
06 0000004c`9cdff030 00007ff8`381184c3 : 00000209`6e8e4aa0 00000000`00000002 0000004c`9cdff370 0000004c`9cdff0b0 : ucrtbase!__crt_seh_guarded_call<void>::operator()<<lambda_aa87e3671a710a21b5dc78c0bdf72e11>,<lambda_92619d2358a28f41a33ba319515a20b9> & __ptr64,<lambda_6992ecaafeb10aed2b74cb1fae11a551> >+0x32
07 0000004c`9cdff060 00007ff8`381183e5 : 00000209`6e8e4aa0 00007ff8`381fbb70 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000004 : ucrtbase!construct_ptd+0xb7
08 0000004c`9cdff0a0 00007ff8`38124031 : 00000000`00000000 00000209`6e8e4aa0 00000209`6e8e4aa0 00000000`7ffe0384 : ucrtbase!construct_ptd_array+0x29
09 0000004c`9cdff0d0 00007ff8`3b088f07 : 00000209`6e8e4aa0 00000000`7ffe0385 00000000`00000002 00000000`7ffe0385 : ucrtbase!DllMainDispatch+0xa9
0a 0000004c`9cdff100 00007ff8`3b086896 : 00000209`1eea3c90 00007ff8`38110000 0000004c`00000002 00007ff8`38a9f3d0 : ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x6f
0b 0000004c`9cdff170 00007ff8`3b0b5745 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x15a
```

This thread appears to be waiting on some critical section; specifically 00007ff8`381fc1d0.

Looking at the held critical sections in the process to figure out why this is blocked we find:

```
!locks
CritSec ntdll!LdrpLoaderLock+0 at 00007ff83b19f4f8
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          0
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       1b50 //71
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    2
*** Locked

CritSec ucrtbase!_acrt_stdout_buffer+3d0 at 00007ff8381fc1d0
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          6
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       4e4 //9
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    8
*** Locked
```

Thread 71 currently holds the loader lock, however the critical section it appears to be waiting on is some sort of IO buffer held by thread 4e4 (AKA thread 9 from above).

Inspecting thread 9 we see the following:

```
Kv
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
05 0000004c`901fd830 00007ff8`2329d4c1 : 00000000`00000006 00000209`3a48abd0 00000000`00000003 00007ff8`00000080 : clr!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x2b**
06 0000004c`901fd860 00007ff8`232a263d : 00000209`3a48abd0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`000027df : clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x180
07 0000004c`901fd8f0 00007ff8`231e4564 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000209`3a48abd0 00000000`00000110 : clr!JIT_RareDisableHelperWorker+0x4d
08 0000004c`901fda40 00007fff`79ea45dc : 00000000`00000004 0000004c`901fdb20 00000000`00000000 00000001`00000000 : clr!JIT_RareDisableHelper+0x14
!clrstack
0000004c901fdaa8 00007ff83b0df6f4 [InlinedCallFrame: 0000004c901fdaa8] .std._Lockit._Lockit_ctor(Int32)
0000004c901fdaa8 00007fff79ea45bd [InlinedCallFrame: 0000004c901fdaa8] .std._Lockit._Lockit_ctor(Int32)
0000004c901fda80 00007fff79ea45bd DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(Int32)
0000004c901fdb30 00007fff79ea449c .std.use_facet >(std.locale*) [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xlocale @ 559]
0000004c901fdb80 00007fff79ea437d .std.use_facet >(std.locale*)
0000004c901fdc00 00007fff79e9dcd5 .std.basic_filebuf >.open(std.basic_filebuf >*, SByte*, Int32, Int32) [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\fstream @ 271]
0000004c901fdc60 00007ff7c47beabb .std.basic_ifstream >.open(std.basic_ifstream >*, SByte*, Int32, Int32) [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\fstream @ 896]
0000004c901fdca0 00007ff744d9ca28 .Calculator.run_Algorithm_GetTable_ASCII(Calculator*, Single**)
0000004c901fe330 00007ff744d9bf01 .Calculator.run_Calculate(Calculator*)
0000004c901fe370 00007ff744d9ba38 .perform_Calculation(Int32, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, Int32, Single, Int32, Single, Single, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, SByte*, Int32, Single*, Single*, Single*)
0000004c901fe8f0 00007ff8231e222e [InlinedCallFrame: 0000004c901fe8f0] MySecondManagedCProject.perform_Calculation(Int32, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, Int32, Single, Int32, Single, Single, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, System.String, Int32, Single ByRef, Single ByRef, Single ByRef)
0000004c901fe830 00007ff744d988ec DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(Int32, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, Int32, Single, Int32, Single, Single, Single, Single, Single, Int32, Int32, System.String, Int32, Single ByRef, Single ByRef, Single ByRef)
0000004c901fec80 00007ff744d954fc MyCSharpProject.Calculate(MyCSharpProject.Settings)
0000004c901fed40 00007ff7c3aaf033 [MulticastFrame: 0000004c901fed40] System.EventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
0000004c901feda0 00007ff744d951b1 MyCSharpProject.OnDataReceived(System.EventArgs)
0000004c901fef50 00007ff7c43e25d5 MyCSharpProject.NotifyThread()
```

Thread 9 holds the lock thread 71 needs to continue by virtue of opening a file stream to load configuration data for the "calculation".  However thread 9 is blocked until GC is complete, so can never release the critical section the filestream seems to take.

At this point I am unclear what course of action to take.  If my analysis is correct file IO from one of my c++ projects can cause a deadlock during GC - however this conclusion seems unlikely considering file I/O is such a common operation, I would expect an issue like this to be quite widespread and critical, rather than something unique to my application that only occurs rarely.

Am I missing something obvious in my diagnosis?  Or is there an avenue of investigation I've neglected?

Comment: Options for testing: 1) you can preallocate memory for your file O/I at start up and pass those buffers to your C++ threads. OR 2) don't actually allocate any heap memory in your C++ thread but use large stack allocation instead. Lastly, and my favorite, 3) don't use a mixed language approach, If you can, make everything C++ or C# and avoid the issue altogether.